# Align tooltips to the left margin of a common paragraph

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip

I have CSS3-defined tooltips of the form `<a><span class="tooltip">tooltip text</span>link text</a>`. When the pointer hovers over the link, a tooltips shows, placed relatively to the beginning of a respective link. I would like, though, the left border of each tooltip to be aligned with the left border of the paragraph, which contains all of the links in question.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xk2zvLy/10

There are two tooltips in the fiddle, which follow y positions of the links, as they should. Yet, they also have different x positions. I would like both to be horizontally aligned with the paragraph.

Can it be done using javascript? I tried the following:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < balloons.length; ++i) {
      var b = balloons[i];
      b.style.left = -b.parentNode.offsetLeft + "px";
  }
```

and different variations; `b` is the `span` with the tooltip. Strangely, some of the variations seemed to work sometimes, i.e. the tooltip appeared exactly where it should, yet only occasionally.

Comment: Can you show an image of what you're hoping/trying for?

Comment: JSFiddle example of what you have so far would get you a response very quickly

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? It sounds as though this can be done with css alone.

Comment: Yes, I will make a fiddle, you are right.

Comment: The fiddle is there.

Comment: you can set your tooltips `position: fixed` and in your js set top and left by getting the `a` elements `.offset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like, though, the left border of each tooltip to be aligned with the left border of the paragraph, which contains all of the links in question.

This is exactly what is happening, since you have the `<span class="translation" />` absolutely positioned relative to the `<a>` tag. Your second `<a>` tag starts with C'était... and in this case mid sentence so this is where the `<span>` translation aligns too.

Try setting `display: table;`

```
a.tooltip:hover .translation {
    display: table;
    opacity: 1.0;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple tooltip / ballon with CSS3 example here and I updated it with a left align zero in the second link. Hope this helps :)

http://jsfiddle.net/mkoL8q5z
http://jsfiddle.net/mkoL8q5z/1/

```
<div title="Tooltip text for first div"></div>
<div title="Tooltip text for second div"></div>

<style>
body{
padding:60px;
}

div{
width:20px;
height:31px;
background:red;
float:left;
margin:0 0 0 20px;
}

div:before{
content:attr(title);
display:none;
}

div:hover{
z-index:10;
position:relative;
}

div:hover::before{
width:200px;
display:block;
background:yellow;
border:1px solid black;
padding:8px;
margin:25px 0 0 0px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I meant something different. I attached a fiddle to illustrate it better.